# how to show multiple file names using react js

Tags: reactjs

How to show the multiple files using select field,
want  to display the no of files which i have been selected but it is only showing single file

```
const [lessonImage, setLessonImage] =  React.useState([]);

const handleLessonImage = (event) => {
  setLessonImage(event.target.files);
} 

 <input 
    type="file" 
    onChange={handleLessonImage}
    multiple
 />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access name of file from File Object.

Link to [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-hooks-dfuqn?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [lessonImage, setLessonImage] = React.useState([]);

  const handleLessonImage = (event) => {
    const data = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
      data.push(event.target.files[i]);
    }
    setLessonImage((old)=> […old,data]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <input type="file" onChange={handleLessonImage} multiple />

      {lessonImage.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <h3>{item.name}</h3>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: while adding other one, previous file is removing

Comment: @Mohan I have updated the code.  Please accept and upvote my answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I added `setLessonImage((old)=> [...old,...data])` it worked